# Sync Outlook Calendar with Sharepoint Calendar and Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization, outlook, sharepoint

I am looking for a way to do a somewhat complicated sync between my work and personal calendars using the cloud based Google Calendar. I was hoping someone in the community had some ideas?

I currently have the following calendars:

**Google Calendar** (2 calendars 1 for personal 1 for work).

**Outlook Calendar** (work)

**Sharepoint Calendar** (work)

I would like to keep my Google work calendar in sync with my Outlook calendar & Sharepoint calendar. For example:

1. Add an event to the Outlook calendar and have that event sync to the Sharepoint calendar and also the Google work calendar.
2. Add an event to the Google work calendar and have it sync to the Outlook
   calendar & the Sharepoint calendar.
3. Add an event to the Sharepoint calendar and have it sync to the Outlook & Google work calendar.

Is there a way that this can be done?

Update:

I found an article on how to work with both an Outlook calendar and a Sharepoint calendar.

Now I just need to figure out the Outlook -----> Google Calendar sync to a non primary Google Calendar. And then a reverse of Google Calendar (non primary) to Outlook Calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly I don't know anything about Sharepoint, so I don't know if any of these solutions will incorporate that. But there are a lot of ways to sync Google with Outlook.

[Google/Outlook Sync](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/outlook_sync.html#utm_source=en-ha-na-us-sk&utm_medium=ha&utm_term=sync%20outlook)

[Sync2](http://www.sync2.com/default.asp)

[Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/sync/pc.html)

[Lifehacker's Guide to syncing Google Calendar with any desktop app](http://lifehacker.com/399407/how-to-sync-any-desktop-calendar-with-google-calendar)

Comment: Thanks Emmys, from what I understand the Google Sync Calendar tool only allows you to sync to your default Google calendar. My problem is that I have multiple Google calendars defined and want to sync to my work Google calendar which is not my default calendar.

Comment: It's not a free service, but check out the Sync2 link - they do indicate that you can sync to multiple Google calendars (http://sync2.com/share_outlook_and_google_calendar_sync.asp)

Comment: Thanks I will check it out. If anyone knows any free solutions please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out gSyncIt. It will sync between multiple calendars in Google and Outlook, works very well for me (and has a ton of other features).

http://www.daveswebsite.com/software/gsync/

Comment: Thanks for the info. When I have the ability to I will "up vote" your response.